# Selecting rows that doesn't have duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
| sku | id | value | count |
|-----|----|-------|-------|
| A   | 1  | 1     | 2     |
| A   | 1  | 2     | 2     |
| A   | 3  | 3     | 3     |
```

I want to select rows that don't have the same count for the same id. So my desired outcome is:

```
| sku | id | value | count |
|-----|----|-------|-------|
| A   | 3  | 3     | 3     |
```

I need something that works with Postgres 10

Comment: By "count" do you mean the `count` column or the number of rows?

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by sku, id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

This assumes you really mean the sku/id combination.